# Howto debug Ajax request at server side with Netbeans?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, debugging

I have a button on a page where I do:

```
$.post("../somefolder/myfile.php",{option:"somevar", anotherParam:"aParam", andAnother:"YouCanImagine"},function (myData)
{
      doSomething();
});
```

What I want is to NetBeans get stopped when reach a breakpoint I have on myFile.php, when I press the button in the website. I have debug working, what I can't get it working is debug ajax requests (and don't know if possible".

I readed a lot, and tried adding..

```
$.post("../somefolder/myfile.php?XDEBUG_START_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug" ....
```

but didn't worked. Then I tried to pass as post with

```
...myfile.php",{option:"somevar", anotherParam:"aParam", andAnother:"YouCanImagine", XDEBUG_SESSION_START: "netbeans-xdebug" ..
```

With same result.
I have easiest Xdebug extension on Firefox, and I see how XDEBUG_SESSION is added as cookie with the request.

My question is, is possible to do What I try to achieve? Or I'm just going crazy all day trying, and is not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Open firebug and run ajax query
2. View request headers of your request in firebug
3. Click right mouse button and choose "Copy cURL"
4. Put the code to console terminal and add to request url a param
   "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug"

Then start debug session in netbeans and run query from console.